# How can I enable strict data type checking when using fluent interface in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

The following code passes the test when run. How can I change this so that it complains about the difference between `123` and `'123'`?

```
$obj = $this->getMockBuilder('Namespace\Object')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$obj
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('do')
    ->with($this->equalTo('123')); // String

$obj->do(123);
```

How can I enable strict data type checking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `with` function takes a `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint`.

The list of those can be found [**in the source**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php#L2108)

What i think you are looking for is:

```
->with($this->identicalTo('123'));
```